# Excel VBA: How to stop program and return to certain step in code, 'bypassing modal limitations of MsgBox'

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, userform, msgbox

I have a user interface where the user enters some information. Then they press a button for a report to be generated. The user however cannot have left certain files open while the report is generated. If the user leaves a file open, I want an error message to pop up to inform them of this. And then I want a way for the user to fix the problem (close the file) without having to restart the program as they already entered information.

I have the MsgBox pop up:

```
Do While IsFileOpen(wfileName)
    MsgBox "Please close the Weights Machine Data Excel File '" & getFileName(wfileName) & "' to proceed", vbInformation, "Error"

Loop
```

The problem is that the user cannot do any thing once the error message happens. I know that `MsgBox` is modal, but is there a way to get around that. If not I want the user to return to the point before they pressed the `generateReport` Button, so they do not have to retype any of the information they inputted. How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My response is probably more appropriate as a comment instead of an answer - but I don't have enough reputation yet....Anyway

Why not just call the `IsFileOpen(wfileName)` in the generateReport button click event.  If it's true, display your message and then Exit Sub.

Comment: +1. This is appropriate as an answer, IMO, unless there is some esoteric reason why OP *can't* implement it this way.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox results can be captured as a long/integer value. So, you can use them to capture user input, and then route your code accordingly, either by calling other procedures or sending to a `GoTo` statement, etc.

```
Sub Example()
Dim mb as VbMsgBoxResult
ShowAgain:
mb = MsgBox("Do you want to see another message box?", vbYesNo) 

If mb = vbYes Then 
    GoTo ShowAgain
Else:
    'Do something else
End If



End Sub
```

In your case, you might do:

```
Dim mb as vbMsgBoxResult

mb = MsgBox("Please close the Weights Machine Data Excel File '" & getFileName(wfileName) & "' to proceed", vbOkCancel, "Error")

If mb = vbOk Then 
    Workbooks(getFileName(wfileName)).Save
    Workbooks(getFileName(wfileName)).Close
Else:
    'Do something else...

End If
```

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by this:

> I want the user to return to the point before they pressed the generateReport Button, so they do not have to retype any of the information they inputted. How do I go about solving this?
>   But most likely it can't be done *easily* unless the button (and all of the information that the user has "entered" so far) is on a UserForm or stored in a Class object or some other persistent piece of memory, etc..

Is simply saving/closing the file sufficient? That should allow the procedure to continue running without the error that would happen if the file is already open.

Comment: This works fine. On your question, when the user presses `generateReport()`, a driver is called which essentially generates the report. The original location of the `MsgBox` was in a function which the driver called while "generating the report." What I was looking for was essentially the `GoTo` function where the user "goes back to" the user form and can restart the report generation process. Normally, once the report is generated, the user form closes. In this case, how would I make `GoTo` lead back to the filled out UF if the user does not want the program to save and close?

Comment: Would it just be `GoTo` the `CommandButton_Click()` (really the `generateReport_Click()`) sub?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the full code but I think the other answer is on the right track.  Do you close or unload the form? If so, don't do that just set it's .visible=false and then make it visible again if the validation step fails (or unload if the validation passes).

Comment: While I did not use the `GoTo`, I solved my problem by Including your `Sub` in my `User Form`. Then I did not have to use the `GoTo` function. Thanks again for your help.